# VIm Regexp или PCRE. Что полезнее учить?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, vim, perl

Озадачился вопросом изучение regexp'ов. Синтаксис регулярных выражений в vim немного отличается от более распространенных(?) perl'овских ([PCRE](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCRE)).

[VimWikia](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Perl_compatible_regular_expressions) говорит, что надо пользоваться теми regexp'ами, которые вы знаете лучше.

**Вопрос:** какой синтаксис полезнее будет учить? Или разница незначительная и использовать PCRE при случае не составит труда?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PCRE немного пошире, там есть например positive/negative look behind, именованные группы и прочие радости. Знать надо и то и то, в js например что-то среднее между PCRE и ERE Posix, в общем в 90% случаев вам пригодится только набор ERE, а PCRE можно рассматривать как расширение, в regex главное словить тему, остальное очень просто.